# HTML/CSS Bottom Border animated on button

Tags: html, css

Im new to css and html and im trying to make a good looking website for my FiveM RP Server, and im having issues with the buttons

[image: i wanna make the bottom line animated from center]

```css
a:visited {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:link {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:after {
  border-bottom: solid 3px #019fb6;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out;
}

a:hover {
  color: green;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #004F10;
  transform: scaleX'(1);

}

a:active {
  color: darkgreen;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <ul>
    <h2><a href="index.html">Home</a></h2>
    <h2><a href="rules.html">Rules</a></h2>
    <h2><a href="https://www.discord.gg/K935Cry73b">Discord</a></h2>
  </ul>
</header>
```

Comment: ya but whats the issue

Answer (score 1):

I have displayed the "a" tag as an inline-block so that it doesn't occupy the whole container width.

In your code, you forgot to add content property. And the hover is applied to the ::after selector of the "a" tag not the "a" tag itself. Here is the fix to your code.

```
a{
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a::after {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  border-bottom: solid 3px darkgreen;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out;
}

a:hover::after{
    transform: scaleX(1);
}

a:active{
    color: darkgreen;
}

a:visited{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: thank you this did exactly what i needed, thank you so much

Comment: @Normal Welcome to StackOverflow. [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Check this CodePen from Peter, he did exactly what you want.

Code:

```
<nav>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">item1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">item2</a></li>
      <li class="different"><a href="">item3</a></li>
      <li class="different"><a href="">item4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
body, html{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color: #999999;
}

*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  list-style:none;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

nav{
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px; 
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left:0;
  background-color: #333333;
}

#wrapper{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

#wrapper ul{
  diplay: block;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

#wrapper li{
  display: block;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all ease-in-out .2s;
}
#wrapper a{
  display: block;
  float: left;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 .5em;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}
li.different{
  border:none;
  position: relative;
}
li.different:hover{
  border: none;
}
li:hover {
  border-bottom: 5px solid #FFFFFF;
}
.different::after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0px;
  height: 5px;
  left: 50%;
  bottom:0;
  background-color: white;
  transition: all ease-in-out .2s;
}
.different:hover::after{
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/PeterBouSaada/pen/zZzJMa)

Answer (score 0):

There are total 3 animation.

1st with default top-down animation.

2nd with fade animation

3rd with fade and scale animation.

```css
.main-container{
  display: flex;
}
/* First tag */
.testAni {
  font-size: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  color: darkgreen;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
.testAni:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-bottom: 5px solid darkgreen;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 30px;
  transition: 0.5s all ease;
}
.testAni:hover:after {
  top: 100%;
}
/* Second tag */
.testAni2:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-bottom: 5px solid darkgreen;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 30px;
  transition: 0.5s all ease;
  opacity: 0;
}
.testAni2:hover:after {
  top: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
}
/* Third tag */
.testAni3:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-bottom: 5px solid darkgreen;
  transform: scale(0.1);
  left: 0;
  top: 30px;
  transition: 0.5s all ease;
  opacity: 0;
} 
.testAni3:hover:after {
  top: 100%;
  transform: scale(1);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <h2><a class="testAni" href="index.html">Home</a></h2>
  <h2><a class="testAni testAni2" href="index.html">Home</a></h2>
  <h2><a class="testAni testAni2 testAni3" href="index.html">Home</a></h2>
</div>
```